# Create files but not modify the created file or any other file in a directory

Tags: windows, security, file-permissions

Is it possible using Windows standard tools to create such a permission model where a user can  create a file in a directory, but once the file has been created (file handle closed), the user can not modify that file or any other files in the directory?

The use case is that a user submits a file for review, but should not be allowed to modify it after submission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a folder, such as C:\Test\

On the properties of that folder, go to Security -> Advanced, uncheck the box to include inheritable permissions.

Still in Advanced permissions, Add the users or group that you want to be able to drop files in this folder.  Give them these permissions:

> Traverse folder / execute file
>
> List folder / read data
>
> Read attributes
>
> Read extended attributes
>
> Create files / write data
>
> Write attributes
>
> Read permissions

But do not give them "Create folders / apend data"